# How to use foreach function for list tag in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, foreach, html-lists

I want to use for each function for getting all `li` elements in an array using core javascript

```
var li_arr = []
$('li').each(function(){
    li_arr.push($(this).attr("id"));
})
```

this is the code i want to convert

Comment: And what did you attempt?

Comment: [How much effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method to get all li elements, convert it to an array using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and finally use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to generate id array.

```
let li_arr = [...document.querySelectorAll('li')].map(ele => ele.id)
```

```js
let li_arr = [...document.querySelectorAll('li')].map(ele => ele.id)

console.log(li_arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="1">Item 1</li>
  <li id="2">Item 2</li>
  <li id="3">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `document.querySelectorAll('li')`.

```js
const lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');

lis.forEach((li) => {
    console.log(li.id);
});
```

```html
<li id="1">Item 1</li>
<li id="2">Item 2</li>
<li id="3">Item 3</li>
```

If you want to target the `lis` of specific `ul`.

```js
console.log([...document.querySelectorAll('ul#list>li')].map(el => el.id));
```

```html
<ul id="list">
    <li id="1">Item 1</li>
    <li id="2">Item 2</li>
    <li id="3">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```js
<script>
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

var li_arr = []
for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
    
     li_arr.push(all[i].getAttribute("id"))
}

console.log(li_arr)
</script>
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="1">Item 1</li>
  <li id="2">Item 2</li>
  <li id="3">Item 3</li>
  <li id="4">Item 4</li>
</ul
```